# PHP submit form causes a 404 in Firefox but works fine in Chrome

Tags: php, html, forms, phpstorm

I am having issues when a form is submitted instead of a php page being called I get a 404 error.

Both files are in the same directory and I am using PHPStorm as the IDE and Xampp as the php interpreter. Once the submit button is clicked it tries to open the right page: 
http://localhost:63342/untitled/learn.php BUT that just gives a 404 message. Oddly then if I press enter on that URL it does take me to the php page just fine, which is really confusing. This however is not an issue using Chrome and only happens in Firefox. The code I used is shown below:

Html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tutorial page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="learn.php" method="post">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>UserName</td>

            <td align="center"> <input type="text" name="username" size="30"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

php page:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Information gathered</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php

    echo "testing this";

    ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `action="learn.php"`. try it in all browser and check. As you said that both files are in same directory

Comment: You probably got the URL to the file wrong, also why do you have type="hidden" in your form?

Comment: `action` attribute of form expects a URL. So try only `learn.php` or the full url.

Comment: tried on other browsers and it only works on Chrome, firefox and IE give a 404. Removed the "hidden" and changed to learn.php and still nothing.

Comment: You are using PhpStorm's own simple built in web server -- it has some issues with POST requests. I suggest using proper Apache/IIS/nginx instead (XAMPP/WAMP/MAMP/whatever) to serve your pages.

Comment: @LazyOne Switching from PhpStorm's server to XAMPP fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @Bright It should be fixed in recent and latest **2017.2.2** -- had few positive feedbacks/confirmations. But using XAMPP or any other proper web server is better in general (more close to real environment/more functionality etc).

Comment: @LazyOne `502 Bad Gateway

PhpStorm 2017.2.2` unfortunately, 2017.2.2 does not fix it in my case. Although the new version did fix Chrome.

Comment: [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15680069) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67145917) saying "This appears to only be an issue when running via PHPStorm."

Answer (score 0):

`action` attribute of `form` expects a URL. So try only `learn.php` or some full url.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

> The URI of a program that processes the form information. This value
>   can be overridden by a formaction attribute on a  or 
>   element.

`.` notation is used in command line generally to denote current directory. I am not sure if same can be used in URL.

Comment: didn't change anything as I did have it before as action="learn.php"

Comment: @user1031204 also check access and error log of apache. which url is it exactly trrying to acccess, you will know.

Comment: using full URL does the same thing as it already gets the right URL from the start "http://localhost:63342/untitled/learn.php"

I also checked the apache logs and were we no errors.

Comment: @user1031204 `does the same thing` shows the error ? you mean `localhost:63342/untitled/learn.php` works in chrome but throws 404 error in firefox ?

Comment: If you manually type in the URL into the browser both work just fine. It only does not work on firefox when a post is used in the HTML page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114597/discussion-between-jigar-and-user1031204).